# Spring Boot / Spring Data Jpa: Where is the property "spring.datasource.driverClassName" read in the java code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, application.properties

I have gone through the [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) reference page. This contains the list of commonly used spring props.

So, just to explore and find out the **convention** regarding how and where the above props are declared (read) in java code. I decided to set sailing towards finding `spring-data-jpa` related properties. I started to find for the java code where `spring.datasource.driverClassName` property is declared (read).

I have looked at these jars:

1. `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.7.RELEASE.jar` - this seems to be only a meta jar not a code jar.
2. `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.1.10.RELEASE.jar` - even this jar seems to not have the declaration(reading) for this property. Or I missed locating it.

**Where else should I look? Any suggestions.**

I am Just trying to understand spring boot a little deeper.

As debugmode pointed, I understand that we define the value of the property in the .props or .yml file. I am looking for the code where its read.

Comment: properties of datasource are located in application.properties or .yaml file

Comment: @debugmode - I understand that we define the value of the property in the .props or .yml file. I am looking for the code where its read.

Comment: You need to search spring-boot for the defaults, spring-data is not aware of these... [DatabaseDriver(enum)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DatabaseDriver.java) could give you good links in IDE..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to `spring.datasource.driverClassName` I think you were not looking yet in the right place, as JPA is already an abstraction layer above JDBC.

You should look in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure`. There you'll find `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties` which is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")` and there you'll find `public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName)`

Comment: verified and this answers precisely. +1

Comment: could you help with finding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` props and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics`.  I looked at `spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm` but could not find any.

Comment: You're looking in the right place, but it's a little less straightforward here. `spring.jpa.properties` are mapped to JpaProperties.properties HashMap.

Look further at `HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties()` to get a sense of the logic for these specific Hibernate properties you're asking about. (And `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` for the list of these hibernate properties). If I understand correctly there should be a K-V pair for key `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` in your JpaProperteries.properties object.

Comment: the above comment solves it +1 --> here it goes [AvailableSettings.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java#L1294)

Comment: And Thomas - looking at the AvailableSettings is really wonderful - coz you see the entire feature set. For example - [hibernate.query.plan_cache_enabled](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java#L1405) and there are many more such things here.