# Spring Boot / Spring Data Jpa: Where is the property "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics" read in the java code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have gone through the [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) reference page. This contains the list of commonly used spring props and the values of these properties can be defined in application.properties or application.yml.

So, just to explore and find out the **convention** regarding how and where the above props are declared (read) in java code, I started to search the code for `spring-data-jpa` related properties.

Now, from this SOF answer:

- [Spring Boot / Spring Data Jpa: Where is the property "spring.datasource.driverClassName" read in the java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180858/4820101)

I could see that `spring.datasource.driverClassName` property is located at `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties` i.e at [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java#L72)

Similarly I want to locate the code for other properties like - `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` props and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics`. I looked at `spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm` but could not find any.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

I am Just trying to understand spring boot a little deeper.

Note: I could locate [`spring.jpa`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties.java#L37) but not the above props.

Comment: If you found `spring.jpa`, I see also `properties` ...(Map<String,String>) (this gets passed to the "jpa-provider" as is)

Comment: @xerx593 - so where else to look for all the props that the specific implementation is using.  Finding extensive list of props with all the possible values seems interesting and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such behaviour is mentioned in the docs [Binding Maps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps) (about [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding)) as follows :

> Binding a.b=c to Map<String, String> will preserve the . in the key
> and return a Map with the entry {"a.b"="c"}

`JpaProperties` is now defined as

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jpa")
public class JpaProperties {

    /**
     * Additional native properties to set on the JPA provider.
     */
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    .....
}
```

The prefix is `spring.jpa` and this map field name is `properties`. So given the following properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.foo=bar
```

will bind to this properties map with the following entries:

```
key=hibernate.cache.use_query_cache, value=true
key=foo, value=bar
```

This properties map will be directly feed into following [`JPA API`](https://javadoc.io/static/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) to create the `EntityManagerFactory` :

```java
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("somePersistenceUnit", properties)
```

So from the spring-boot 's point of view , the values of this properties map is transparent to it. Spring boot will not care if the value in this properties map is valid or not as it just simply passes it to Hibernate to let it handle.

So if you want to know all the possible values for the properties , you have to check with hibernate source codes but not the spring-boot.

Comment: this answers it pretty much. +1